# Using grep to search for a string

Tags: search, grep

I wanted to search for this particular string `$string['site:config']` in my folder. But when I use a normal grep function `grep -r "$string['site:config']"` it gives me random results.

Comment: @ylabidi: So, in this case I cannot search for this particular string?

Comment: use -F to force grep to interpret the given pattern as a normal string and not as a regex.

Comment: The problem with your pattern is that characters like $ [ ] are characters used to define regular expressions and you have either to escape them or instruct grep to look for the given string as is, without attempting to interpret it as a regular expression.

Comment: Switch over to TextCrawler instead \o/

Comment: How's that working for you ?

Comment: Great. I reformulated that into a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your pattern is that characters like `$ [ ]` are characters used to define regular expressions and you have either to escape them:

```
grep "\$string\['site:config'\]"
```

or instruct grep to look for the given string as is:

```
grep -F "$string['site:config']"
```

without attempting to interpret it as a regular expression.